# What is the meaning of this compliment: "Your name suits you to a T"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I find this sentence in a post about "100 compliments..." but can not guess what it means. Thank you

Comment: There are numerous theories of the origin of this idiom. The most persusive holds that it references the archaic word _tittle,_ which describes the tiny dot we write over a lower-case _i_ and _j._ A good exposition of the theory is [**here.**](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-meaning-of-to-a-t/)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Seems to be a typo in "persusive".  Persuasive?

Comment: @Rompey Perfection in commentary is unattainable.

Answer (score 8):

The expression means that your character fits your name. This might apply with such names as Joy and Felicity that express emotional states. In parts of Africa (where I spent many years) it is common to give babies names like Delight, Happy, Welcome, Beauty and Miracle, expressing the parents'attitude to the birth.

The roots of the expression "to a T" are uncertain although there is speculation that it might refer to a T-square, an instrument used by draftsmen in the days before sophisticated computer programmes. Others think it might be derived from the phrase "to a tittle", dating back to at least the 17th century.

http://grammarist.com/usage/to-a-t/
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_a_T

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a compliment depending on your name.
In real life Ive only heard this a few times and a majority of those utterances were targeted at a certain Mr Prat that I happened to be acquainted with, who to put it mildly, was an idiot.